# 4-Vector Upstairs vs Bottom Indexing

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, notation

In placing the index top or bottom, I know that it's irrelevant for spacial components, but flips the sign temporally in the 4-position. Does this temporal flip extend to any 4-vector? I.e. for the arbitrary 4-vector $A^\mu$, is it true that $A^0 + A_0 = 0$ and $A^i - A_i = 0$?

Comment: All 4-vectors behave the same way, so yes.

Comment: Does anything like this extend to general tensors seen in relativity? I know the metric tensor doesn't ($\eta_{\mu\nu} = eta^{\mu\nu}$ correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In relativity, the way to convert an upstairs index into a downstairs one is to act the metric tensor on it, by which I mean:
$$A_\mu = g_{\mu\nu}A^\nu$$
In Special Relativity, spacetime is flat and the metric tensor is the simple Minkowski metric:
$$g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu}$$
The convention as to which indices of $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ are negative varies, but it seems the convention you are using is
$$\eta_{\mu\nu} = \text{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$$
which then gives
$$A_0 = -A^0$$
and
$$A_i = A^i$$
This is valid for any 4-vector in this spacetime.

*Note that some texts will use $\eta_{\mu\nu} = \text{diag}(+1,-1,-1,-1)$, and so one would get $A_0 = A^0$ and $A_i = -A^i$.  It doesn't actually matter which you use as long as you are consistent of course!*